# Getting Epson workforce 435 to work in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: drivers, printing

I have been trying to get my **Epson Workforce 435** all in one wireless printer/scanner to work in Ubuntu 12.04 and no luck. For now, my OS is running within an Oracle Virtual Box 
VM. I have downloaded the following driver packages from Epson:

```
epson-inkjet-printer-201109w_1.0.0-1lsb3.2_i386.deb

epson-inkjet-printer-escpr_1.3.1-1lsb3.2_i386.deb
```

I installed both of them. I then used the printers menu item to install setup the printer. All goes well. But, when I print a test page the status message in the Document Status dialog box says:

> Held for authentication

When I was adding the printer, I was prompted to enter my login and password. I don't understand.

Answer (score 1):

Open a terminal window and stop the cups server:

```
sudo service cups stop
```

Then edit the printers.conf file with a good editor 'gedit'

```
sudo vim /etc/cups/printers.conf
```

Near the top of file "/etc/cups/printers.conf" is a line like below

```
AuthInfoRequired username,password
```

Comment it out by inserting a "#"

```
#AuthInfoRequired username,password
```

save the updates and restart the cups server

```
sudo service cups start
```

Comment: OK, now the epson printer is going nuts! Because it is a wireless printer, I connected it to my pc, temporarily, via with a usb cable. I was going to remove the cable.Also, I have my linux os running within Oracle's Virtual Box. Now when I open up the linux VM and have the printer connected via it's usb cable, it immediately starts printing blank pages and won't stop until I disconnect the usb cable. I then deleted the epson printer from the list of printers in the printer queue. Reconnected the usb cable and well it starts printing blank pages. OK, now sure what is going on but??? Any ideas?

Comment: here, take a look at this [thread](http://askubuntu.com/questions/124779/the-network-printer-will-only-print-blank-pages-and-will-not-stop-what-should-i)

Comment: Olu, I looked at that thread and others and I now have the printer working wirelessly in Ubuntu. The key was using socket://full_ip_address. That did it. I had to go through my router to find it. Now, lets see if I can get the scanner to work! Thanks again

Comment: As long as it helped. doesn't matter where it came from